# Why Xamarin Studio Installation Affects Visual Studio MVC 5 Project's View Intellisense And Syntax Recognition?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, xamarin-studio

I have Visual Studio 2012 and have both - MVC 4 and MVC 5 Projects that work fine.

If I go to any of my MVC 4 Projects and Open any .vbhtml file = the syntax and code highlighting is there, code completion, no errors when trying to build a project. The same with MVC 5 projects...

If I install Xamarin Studio - my MVC 4 project's .vbhtml stuff is all working fine but MVC 5 project's .vbhtml stuff is no more recognizable by Visual Studio. If I uninstall Xamarin studio it is back to normal and being recognizable again.

I have read and went through about every post there and there is no unified solution to the problem. Here is some to consider but you should not go through all the hoops just to get your previously working projects back to work only because you install Xamarin Studio.

- You can create an MVC 4 Project and copy all the controllers, models and views there and that is one of the dirty and undesirable ways around it.
- You can change versions of Razor and some other dlls from like 3.0 to 2.0 and play around with it until it works.

The real problem is we should not do all that. We should be able to install Xamarin Studio and not expect to be surprised by how it affected other project types.

This problem could be easily reproduced and like I mentioned before I have seen people struggling with their MVC 5 Projects after installing Xamarin Studio.

One of my clients asked me to make some change to his web projects and I happened to use MVC 5 for this projects just to keep up with latest and greatest (not that I could not upgrade it down the road but why if you can just create a new one when it is available). I wasted 3 hours of my time trying to get the Syntax to work. I ended up uninstalling Xamarin studio - adding a feature to my MVC 5 project and installing Xamarin Studio again because I also have some Mobile App Projects that I develop using Xamarin Studio.

It has been a problem for a long time and I am just trying to find a long term solution without having to mess with my existing MVC 5 projects and without having uninstalling Xamarin Studio everytime I need to make a change to my MVC 5 projects.

Like always my brothers and sisters - you suggestions are highly appreciate it